# Gammu - TextDecoded converted it self

Tags: yii2, sms-gateway, gammu

I just created an SMS gateway feature in my web that powered by Yii2 using gammu.

Based on the tutorial of sending SMS through our web with gammu using query, the message that we created stored in `Outbox` table. Then, when the message is successfuly sent, it would be stored in `SentItems` table.

Here's my problem. Why the `TextDecoded` in Outbox table show me some text like "Send SMS through web" (that text is exactly the same text when I create an SMS in my web form), but `TextDecoded` in SentItems table show me a symbol ? Not the exact same text in `Outbox.TextDecoded`

These are the pictures :

- Message from web that saved to Outbox :  [TextDecoded in this picture is labeled by "Isi Pesan"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1c2sP.jpg)
- TextDecoded in Sentitems : [At the first line of the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Srzcp.jpg)

Comment: Is ``Text`` empty in the database? Otherwise it's used instead of ``TextDecoded``. Also is the message sent correctly?